# Responsive Video, serving image for mobile

Tags: video, responsive-design

I want to be able to serve an image with a link, instead of a video player for a mobile device.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 <video controls="false" autoplay="autoplay">
   <source src="img/sds.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-width:600px)"> 
</video>
```

on a device with widths below 600px I want to just show html, without the video, is it possible to do this inside the video tag? Or do I have to hide the whole video tag and replace it with a div tag that shows up only in mobile?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with media queries in the source tag the way you describe. You have to do it in CSS, something like:

```
@media all  and (max-width : 600px) {
video{
    display:none;
    }
}
```